# Converting integer so it has two decimal places in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable called 'totalMonthly like follows:

```
var totalMonthly: Float = 0.00
```

I then have a function which gets called on viewDidLoad which pulls an array of values from an API request, and loops through them, adding them on to the totalMonthly variable.

This function also contains a Dispatch so that I can render the variable on my screen upon page load inside of a monthlyLabel text label.

```
func calculateMonthly() {
    for account in accounts {
        totalMonthly += Float(account.repaymentTotal)!
        print(account.repaymentTotal)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(self.totalMonthly)
        self.monthlyLabel.text = "£\(self.totalMonthly)"
    }
}
```

However, the values are always showing with just one decimal place - for example it might be 690.0, or 720.2.

I want them instead to display as 690.00, or 720.20.

I have tried converting it into a %.2f format as a string, but that just automatically makes the variable change to 0.00 and render that on the screen.

For reference, the values pulled from the API are stored as flat values (230, 540 etc), so I figured I'd need to convert them into floats, but no luck.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked into using [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) for displaying the values correctly for various currencies and locales? You can use it to set [`minimumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1410459-minimumfractiondigits) to control the number of digits after the decimal place.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Got it working.